# C++ wait for key press when the console window is inactive

Tags: c++, input, iostream

I want to wait for key press and read the key on Windows  in C++ console application.
Now I'm using `getch()`, but it doesn't receive key press when is console window inactive. Is there some (ideally simple) way to detect key press, with inactive console window?

Comment: On which platform? There is no way to do that in the standard library

Comment: I thought about doing it with the standard library :-(

Comment: The standard library mostly only supports things which are implementable on almost any platform and likely to be used by a lot of people, globally spying on the keyboard doesn't really fit into either category so you have to use platform specific code

Comment: Sorry, I forgot platform can mean OS (I'm not from an English-speaking country). I'm using Windows.